# Use vars from before WITH statement in RETURN statement in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm starting with Neo4j (v2.1.5) and I'm having an issue with the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (actor:Person{name:"Tom Cruise"})-[role:ACTED_IN]->(movies)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(coactors)
WITH  coactors, count(coactors) as TimesCoacted
RETURN coactors.name, avg(TimesCoacted)
ORDER BY avg(TimesCoacted) DESC
```

It is based on the mini movie graph which comes with Neo4j installation.

Everything works fine, it shows all *coactors* which coacted in movies with Tom Cruise and *how many times they coacted together*, **but the problem occurs when I want to list in which movies they coacted**. Placing 'movies' variable in RETURN statement is throwing the following error:

```
movies not defined (line 3, column 9)
"RETURN  movies, coactors.name, avg(TimesCoacted)"
         ^
```

Is there any way I can do it in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MATCH 
    (actor:Person{name:"Tom Cruise"})-[role:ACTED_IN]->(movies)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(coactors)
WITH 
    coactors, 
    count(coactors) as TimesCoacted, 
    movies // You have declare "movies" here in order to use it later in the query
RETURN 
    movies, 
    coactors.name, 
    avg(TimesCoacted)
ORDER BY 
    avg(TimesCoacted) DESC
```

What you define in the `WITH`-statement is the only thing that is available for further processing. In the original question the `movies` were not carried on to the next section (it was not part of `WITH`) and therefore `movies` could not be used in the return statement.

**Edit:** After updates from the OP the following was added.

Another example. If you wish to count the number of times the actors have *coacted* in a movie and list the movie-titles as well. Try the following:

```
MATCH 
    (actor:Person {name:"Tom Cruise"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coactor:Person)
WITH
    actor,
    coactor,
    collect (distinct movie.title) as movieTitles
RETURN
    actor.name as actorName, 
    coactor.name as coactorName, 
    movieTitles, 
    size(movieTitles) as numberOfMovies
```

Comment: And if you want to aggregate across movies use `WITH collect(distinct movie.title) as movies`

Comment: I tried this before, but it is not what i was looking for. 

This query doesn't aggregate times actors coacted. In this example, Cuba Googing Jr. appears two times:

movie: A Few Good Men
actor: Cuba Gooding Jr. 
timescoacted 1

movie: Jerry Maguire
actor: Cuba Gooding Jr. 
timescoacted 1

Comment: @SrdjanMarjanovic - so, what are you looking for?

Comment: @wassgren something more like:

actor: Cuba Gooding jr.
timescoacted: 2
movies: A Few Good Men, Jerry Maguire

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH 
    (actor:Person{name:"Tom Cruise"})-[role:ACTED_IN]->(movies)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(coactors)
WITH 
    coactors, 
    count(coactors) as TimesCoacted, 
    collect(DISTINCT movies.title) as movies // <=- this line was crucial! 
RETURN 
    movies, 
    coactors.name, 
    avg(TimesCoacted)
ORDER BY 
    avg(TimesCoacted) DESC
```