# Including vars in Neo4j WITH statement changes query output

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find the number of nodes of a certain kind in my database that are connected to more than one other node of another kind. In my case, it's place nodes connected to several name nodes. I have a query that works:

```
MATCH rels=(p:Place)-[c:Called]->(n:Name) 
WITH p,count(n) as counts 
WHERE counts > 1 
RETURN p;`
```

However, that only returns the place nodes, and ideally I'd like it to return all the nodes and edges involved. I've found [a question on returning variables from before the WITH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903842/use-vars-from-before-with-statement-in-return-statement-in-neo4j-cypher), but if I include any of the other variables I've defined, the query returns no responses, i.e. this query returns nothing:

```
MATCH rels=(p:Place)-[c:Called]->(n:Name) 
WITH p, count(n) as counts, rels
WHERE counts > 1 
RETURN p;
```

I don't know how to return the information that I want without changing the results of the query. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your second query returns nothing is because its `WITH` clause specifies as [aggregation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-aggregation) "grouping keys" both `p` and `rels`. Since each `rels` path has only a single `n` value, `counts` would always be 1.

Something like this might work for you:

```
MATCH path=(p:Place)-[:Called]->(:Name) 
WITH p, COLLECT(path) as paths 
WHERE SIZE(paths) > 1 
RETURN p, paths;
```

This returns each matching `Place` node and all its paths.

Comment: Thank you for linking to the aggregation explanation, it definitely helps me understand what's going on in this situation, with a nice elegant query that works in my database to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (p:Place)-[c:Called]->(n:Name)
WHERE size((p)-[:Called]->(:Name)) > 1
WITH p,count(n) as counts, collect(n) AS names, collect(c) AS calls
RETURN p, names, calls, counts ORDER BY counts DESC;
```

This query makes use of Cypher's `collect()` function to create lists of the names and called relationships for each place that has more than Called relationship with a Name node.

Comment: Thanks for this, your query does work on my database, and it helps to have a better understanding of collect. If only I had more than one acceptance check to give!